# WebView get image URL

Tags: android, image, url, webview, webkit

On my frontend application, I would like to get the images URL shown on WebView in order to render those images as button view. Pictures are provided by backend, they have embedded href as well. My first assumption have been as following- from [How to get link-URL in Android WebView with HitTestResult for a linked image (and not the image-URL) with Longclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168039/how-to-get-link-url-in-android-webview-with-hittestresult-for-a-linked-image-an?rq=1) - to capture the URL:

```
WebView.HitTestResult result = ((WebView) webView).getHitTestResult();

    if (result != null) {
        int type = result.getType();

        // Confirm type is an image
        if (type == WebView.HitTestResult.IMAGE_TYPE || type == WebView.HitTestResult.SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE) {
            String imageUrl = result.getExtra();
            Toast.makeText(this, imageUrl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
```

However it stuck at the first if statement as I can see at debugging.. Will be appreciate for any help!

Best