# Kitkat doesn't return url for requestFocusNodeHref

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a long click listener attached to a webview, inside it I obtain the url associated to an `img` tag, everything works fine on 4.2.2 and 4.3 but now on 4.4 the message data `url` is identical to `src`'s value

[requestFocusNodeHref](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#requestFocusNodeHref%28android.os.Message%29) documentation

Is this a bug?

```
public class ImagePickerActivity extends Activity implements OnLongClickListener {
  ...
  ...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_view);
    webView.setWebViewClient(...);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(...);
    webView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.setTarget(new LongClickHandler(this));
    webView.requestFocusNodeHref(msg);
    return false;
}


private final static class LongClickHandler extends Handler {
    private final ImagePickerActivity activity;

    public LongClickHandler(ImagePickerActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        String url = msg.getData().getString("url");

        // as documentation says, three keys are returned: url, src and title
        // but on kitkat 4.4 url and src are identical
        // on 4.2.2 and 4.3 as written on docs url points to the anchor's href attribute and src to the img.src attribute 
        for (String s : msg.getData().keySet()) {
            System.out
                    .println("ImagePickerActivity.LongClickHandler.handleMessage()" + s + " = " + msg.getData().get(s));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely a bug. I filed https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=323989 to track this, but even if a fix for this lands it might not make its way to devices for a while.

Unfortunately there isn't an easy way to work around this (sorry!), some suggestions (from simplest to most complicated):

- encode the href in the image src URL (requires you to modify the content and that your server ignores some bit of the image src URL, like the query bit),
- if the images have unique URLs use `WebView.evaluateJavascript` to find the image and get the parent's href,
- use JS to detect that the element has been focused and hand the href back to Java via an object exposed to JS via addJavascriptInterface,
- use something like JQuery Mobile [taphold](http://api.jquerymobile.com/taphold/) to handle the long-press in JS,
- use `document.elementFromPoint`. To calculate the CSS coordinates you may need to use `View.getLocationOnScreen` (to go from absolute to WebView-relative coordinates), WebView.getScrollX/Y (to add the WebView scroll offset to the view-relative touch point coordinates) and finally divide by `WebView.getScale()` to get the CSS pixel values. After that you could use `WebView.evaluateJavascript` to get the result.

Comment: Thanks for the long explanation, I can't edit html content, the app reads pages from the web not from my server. Javascript must be disabled on my webView by design so I'm considering to parse HTML myself (with jsoup??), extract images and show them using a grivView.  I've filed a bug, too. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62928

Comment: This bug was address/resolved in https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=323989 as of Jan 2014. Not sure when/if that fix makes its way to existing devices.