# WebView.HitTestResult only getting <img src> Not <a href>

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, webview

I am trying to open new window with android browser using "_blank". I listen with this event.

```
  mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
             mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                 @Override
                 public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean dialog, boolean userGesture, android.os.Message resultMsg)
                 {
                     WebView.HitTestResult result = view.getHitTestResult();
                     String data = result.getExtra();
                     Context context = view.getContext();

                     Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(data));
                     context.startActivity(browserIntent);
                     return false;

                 }

  });
```

But it opens only image url when clicking on Image Link . Not  link. How to get  anchor from WebView.HitTestResult. I don't want to open image type url. Thank you for interesting . Kindly help me Please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168039/how-to-get-link-url-in-android-webview-with-hittestresult-for-a-linked-image-an

Answer (score 1):

Tried many solutions to get the **target page url** not image src, only this one worked:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
    WebView.HitTestResult result = view.getHitTestResult();
    String url = result.getExtra();

    // Ensure that images with hyperlink return the correct URL, not the image source
    if (result.getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE) {
        Message href = view.getHandler().obtainMessage();
        view.requestFocusNodeHref(href);
        Bundle data = href.getData();
        if (data != null) {
            String imageUrl = data.getString("url");
            if (imageUrl != null && !imageUrl.isEmpty()) {
                url = imageUrl;
                //Handle url as you want..
                webView.loadUrl(url);
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Credit goes to [Flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/blob/master/flutter_inappwebview_android/android/src/main/java/com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview_android/webview/in_app_webview/InAppWebViewChromeClient.java)