# OnTouchListener webview always looping

Tags: java, android, webview

i want to detect if i touch edit text type on my webview, i will show the floating action buttons. and if i touch unknown type the floating action buttons will be hide.

but here when i touch some position on my webview, it's looping between 4 / 5 times until i get the real touch type.

here is my code :

```
   @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        WebView.HitTestResult hitTestResult = ((WebView) v).getHitTestResult();

        if (hitTestResult.getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.EDIT_TEXT_TYPE) {
            this.showKeyboard();
            this.floatingActionButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            this.fabKeyboard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            this.hideKeyboard();
            this.floatingActionButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            this.fabKeyboard.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        Log.d("HIT RESULT", hitTestResult.getExtra() + " " + hitTestResult.getType());
        return false;
    }
```

here is my log :

```
I/InputMethodManager: toggleSoftInput(I,I)
D/HIT RESULT: null 9
I/InputMethodManager: toggleSoftInput(I,I)
D/HIT RESULT: null 9
I/InputMethodManager: toggleSoftInput(I,I)
D/HIT RESULT: null 9
D/ViewRootImpl@c99fda4[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/InputMethodManager: toggleSoftInput(I,I)
D/HIT RESULT: null 9 
// 9 IS Edit Text Type

D/HIT RESULT: null 9
D/InputMethodManager: HSIFW - flag : 0
D/HIT RESULT: null 0
D/InputMethodManager: HSIFW - flag : 0
D/HIT RESULT: null 0
D/InputMethodManager: HSIFW - flag : 0
D/HIT RESULT: null 0
D/InputMethodManager: HSIFW - flag : 0
D/HIT RESULT: null 0
// 0 Is Unknown Type
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `mWebview.requestFocus` and use `Handler` process after listen event.
Refer: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#requestFocus(int,%20android.graphics.Rect)
and example: [How to get link-URL in Android WebView with HitTestResult for a linked image (and not the image-URL) with Longclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168039/how-to-get-link-url-in-android-webview-with-hittestresult-for-a-linked-image-an)